# Idiomatic Golang - Readability vs. Runtime Memory Conservation

Tags: go, idioms

Given the two options (as I see them, feel free to enlighten me please), for instance, in checking equality of two strings, I was wondering whether it is preferred/idiomatic in Go to:

Assign the two strings to variables in memory, e.g,:

```
var thing01 := strings.ToLower(strings.Replace(line, "\"", "", -1 ))[:lenEval]
var thing02 := strings.Join(p.FieldsOrder[:p.CheckNHeaders], string(p.Delimiter))

if thing01 == thing02 {
    // do stuff...
}
```

OR

```
if strings.ToLower(strings.Replace(line, "\"", "", -1 ))[:lenEval] == strings.Join(p.FieldsOrder[:p.CheckNHeaders], string(p.Delimiter)) {
    // do stuff...
}
```

Please don't spend time thinking about what `thing01` and `thing02` accomplish, suffice to say if they are equal strings I'd like to address it.

The question is, which is preferred? Assigning into memory with (only slightly, granted) improved readability, or to just 'go for it' and check directly in the `if` statement at run time?

If there is a third option I've overlooked, I'd love to know that too. Thanks all!

**Edit after reading all the great feedback:**

There were several enlightening responses, and I thank all who took the time to consider my quesion. Lessons learned:

- Just because one doesn't assign to a variable, doesn't save it from
  going to the stack (duh).
- Consider readability and maintainability always, for other contributors, and even your future self!
- Use good variable names
- Without advanced knowledge of GC, Compiler, etc. favoring what one things is faster is barking up the wrong tree.

My revised approach:

```
lineFrontSplit := strings.ToLower(strings.Replace(line, `"`, "", -1 ))[:lenLineEval]
colsFrontSplit := strings.Join(p.FieldsOrder[:p.CheckNHeaders], string(p.Delimiter))
if lineFrontSplit == colsFrontSplit {
    return result, nil
}
```

To whoever I annoyed with this apologies, just a newbie looking for insight from the community. If I violated a post guideline please let me know.

Thanks again all.

Comment: The former: the programs are written to be read by programmers. Also consider using backquoted ("raw") string literals when they should otherwise include backslashes.

Comment: Sorry I maybe miss a point, because difference between those if only assign some temporarily expression into variables or not. If you expects, that something is not stored into memory only because it does not have name it is wrong. Please prefer better readable way and stop thinking what is idiomatic. There don't have to be idiom for everything you do.

Comment: Your example might dent the ram from a machine circa 1970.  It's two strings on the stack, I wouldn't worry about it. Readability and simplicity should be your goal.

Comment: I think I would adopt the first method for readability unless I had evidence showing that this specific piece of code was the cause of memory issues / GC overhead.

Comment: The results have to be in memory regardless, whether or not you assign the results to named variables. Any detail beyond that (how long it sticks around, whether it's held in register/stack/heap, etc) is subject to compiler optimizations that vary between OSes, architectures, and Go versions, and which you should not try to control unless it's performance-critical code and profiling shows there is a measurable improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the second version is much less readable. If you give your variables a sensible name (not `thing`) your intention will become clear.

I would not even consider any possible overhead from "assigning to memory", as you put it, because first you do not know whether the compiler optimizes that away and more importantly even if it does not, this is not the bottleneck of your program, not a tight-inner loop of a video editing tool, not the part of your server that is responsible for handling a billion requests per second, or any other example where speed really matters.

Always prefer readability over **what you think** might be slower.

If you really ever have a problem with speed or memory usage of your program, then you can consider improving it (for real and not by "inlining" variables), but in that case you first have to actually profile where your bottlenecks are.

All that said, you could even further improve readability in your program. Depending on what is actually going on you might consider giving `strings.Replace(line, "\"", "", -1 )` its own variable or the `p.FieldsOrder[:p.CheckNHeaders]` part. These are not clear to me at first sight. And they might not be for other readers of your program, e.g. yourself in six months.

Another point: your program says `var thing01 := ...` which is syntactically incorrect. You either say `thing01 := ...` or `var thing01 = ...`. See the difference between `=` and `:=`.

Comment: Accepting this as it makes the most comprehensive argument for what the group consensus seems to me, as well as intuitive sense to me, as you put it, looking out for my self six months from now, or other contributors. @lofcek also makes a good distinction. I'll refactor using the suggestions provided.

Answer (score -1):

**Edited:** Well, idiomatic Go is not too different from common sense many a times. I agree on readability - it is an important factor as maintenance could be a potential nightmare esp. if your expressions get complex. Sometimes building up the expressions by breaking it step by step into easy to understand sub-expressions is also desirable.

However if the expression is simple to understand and expected to remain so, one may want to stick to comparing expressions.